# ObjectOutputStream confusion, need explanation

Tags: java, networking

I'm setting up a server in Java using ObjectOutputStreams and ObjectInputStreams.

```
public class Server {

private ServerSocket socket;

private List<ObjectOutputStream> streams;

public Server() {
    streams = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        socket = new ServerSocket(2000);
        while(true) {
            Socket sock = socket.accept();
            streams.add(new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream()));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
}
```

So, the server needs to be able to receive input from the connections and then send this input to all the connections.

So, when the socket.accept() code executes, I add a new ObjectOutputStream to the Stream ArrayList.

**I'm confused, this ObjectOutputStream, is this going from the Server outputting to the client, or the client outputting to the server?**

Comment: It is the stream used by the server to write to the client .

Comment: It's *output* from the server's perspective, so it's from the server to the client.

Comment: The stream writes to the socket. The socket is read by the client which is connected to the server.

Comment: Thank you very much @Berger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code which listens and accepts connection on a port is the server.

So everything is from the server's point of view.

If you initiate a connection, you are the client and everything will be from the client's point of view.